# Dependency Injection using Template 10

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, template10

I am trying to migrate some code from an old Windows 8.1 app that I had developed using Prism/Unity to a new UWP app using Template 10 and Unity. I have seen in the documentation for Template 10 [here](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Docs-%7C-Bootstrapper#dependency-injection) that you can `override` the `ResolveForPage` method.

In my old Windows 8.1 app, there is a `Resolve` method in Prism that I would `override` like this:

```
protected override object Resolve(Type type)
{
    return Container.Resolve(type);
}
```

The signature for the Template 10 method is

```
public override INavigable ResolveForPage(Page page, NavigationService navigationService)
```

so I am not exactly sure how to convert this. I have registered my repository in `OnInitializeAsync` in my `App.xaml.cs`, like so:

```
Container.RegisterType<IPayeesRepository, PayeesRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Where `Container` is a `UnityContainer` instance. My problem is that when I try to inject the dependency on another page, I get a `NullReferenceException` because `_payeesRepository` is `null`. It seems to me like the constructor with the dependency injection is not being called, and if I remove the default constructor then I get an error. Has anyone gotten Unity to work with Template 10 that may have any suggestions what I may be missing?

I also tried using the `Dependency` attribute like so:

```
[Dependency]
private IPayeesRepository _payeesRepository { get; set; }
```

But that doesn't work either. It seems like the `IPayeesRepository` is just not being instantiated, but I'm not exactly sure. In my Windows 8.1 app, it is never explicitly instantiated, so I have a feeling it has something to do with not overriding the `Resolve` method.

Comment: dub stylee, I'm currently dealing with the same issue and I have to say that there is a lack of examples about this ResolveForPage method... If I find out a solution I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work (but In my case I'm having another anoying issue I'll mention later and probably in a SO quiestion too).

On the one hand, [the *Ask Too Much*'s answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452478/how-do-i-use-a-unity-ioc-container-with-template10) guided me to solve this problem with ViewModel's DI.

In App.xaml.cs:

```
public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    // long-running startup tasks go here
    AppController.Initialize();
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

AppController is the place where I configure the app, including the container.

next, in App.xaml.cs:

```
public override INavigable ResolveForPage(Page page, NavigationService navigationService)
{
    if (page is MainPage)
    {
        return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainPageViewModel>();
        //(AppController.UnityContainer as UnityContainer).Resolve<INavigable>();
    }
    else
        return base.ResolveForPage(page, navigationService);
}
```

But you also have to:

Remove `<Page.DataContext>` from the Page XAML.
Remove constructors from page.xaml.cs, my MainPage.xaml.cs is like this

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    MainPageViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return _viewModel ?? (_viewModel = (MainPageViewModel)DataContext); }
    }    
}
```

Inject your dependencies on your VM:

```
public MainPageViewModel(IShapeService shapeService)
{     
   // this is just a POC            
}
```

And that's all, it should work for you.

[I updated the wiki](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Docs-%7C-Bootstrapper) with this same information in a while... Also, just let you know that I made it to work with Unity and with MVVMLight.SimpleIoC with same result, a System.PlatformNotSupportedException due to what IShapeService really is is a WCF proxy that is in a PCL library that I'll have to refactor because I just realize that UWP doesn't support config files  (lol!)

I hope it helps and save you time.