# Template10 dependency injection for modal dialog

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-injection, template10

I have a Template10 based application with a modal dialog for a login screen as shown in the example at the Template10 GitHub page.

https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Samples/Search

I would like to resolve a login view model using MEF. I'm doing dependency injection as described in the answer to this question.

[Template 10 depency injection using MEF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745561/template-10-depency-injection-using-mef)

Here's an extract of my App.xaml.cs.

```
public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var config = new ContainerConfiguration();
    _container = config.WithAssembly(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly).CreateContainer();
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.MainPage));
}       

public override INavigable ResolveForPage(Page page, NavigationService navigationService)
{
    _container.SatisfyImports(page);
    return (page as IView)?.ViewModel;
}
```

That works fine for views that I navigate to using the navigation service but not my login view. Here's the modal dialog in shell.xaml.

```
<Controls:ModalDialog x:Name="LoginModal"
                          CanBackButtonDismiss="False"
                          DisableBackButtonWhenModal="True">
        <Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
            <views:LoginView x:Name="loginPart"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              HideRequested="LoginHide"
                              LoggedIn="LoginLoggedIn" />
        </Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
    </Controls:ModalDialog>
```

In my login view's code behind, I have this property that I would like to resolve but it's always null.

```
[Import]
public LoginViewModel VM { get; set; }
```

Is there some way to resolve the dependencies of a modal dialog?

**Update**

I've just noticed that the login view gets constructed before App.OnStartAsync is called. I moved the configuration of the IOC container into App.CreateRootElement so that it's done before the login view constructor is hit but the problem remains.

**Update**

A messy partial workaround is to have a static class with a reference to the IOC container and call it from the view's constructor.

```
public LoginView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    IOCContainer.Container.SatisfyImports(this);
 }
```

I would definitely like to avoid relying on a static class like this. However even doing this, the view model's navigation service is null.